# Changing service Log On user account & password from command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, command-line, cmd

I have a service which is using a shared folder from another machine (in the same domain).
In order to get access to the shared folder the service needs to log on as a different user.
before running the installation I use the following command to change the user:
sc config "Service Name" obj= "domain\user" password= "PWD"

I see that the service get the new logon details but fail to start the service becasuse of it.
But if I change the logon details manually, everything is ok and the service starts.

Does anybody have an idea what might cause it? or another way to change the logon details?
the whole process is automated by ansible.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: The account has to be granted the "log on as a service" right, you might for example use `ntrights.exe` from the Windows Server 2003 resource kit.  (If I remember rightly, the GUI interface does this for you automatically.)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  this did the trick!